# First Image in a Series always references /cpresources/transforms/

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I am having some odd behavior with an assets field.

I have an assets field that pulls a series of images. The template pulls the image transforms using {{ asset.getUrl('galleryThumb') }}. Odd thing is, the first image added always references the /cpresources/transforms/(number)b and not the actual file. All the other files work as expected.

I have tried clearing the caches. I tried a rinkydink solution of uploading a dummy image, making it the first and then deleting it... which worked until I cleared the caches again which made the first real image disappear again.

This happens also if I change the getUrl to another transform or even just the {{ asset.url }} so I am assuming it is the field.

The db assettransformsindex has a "0" in the fileExists column, but if I look in the actual transforms folder, it's there and was created.

The field is an assets field set to go to a specific folder in the path settings of the assets field I have the name of the folder(set to 777 out of frustration) "before-and-after" (without quotes and no slashes).

I've seen other questions here regarding images referrencing the /cpresources/transforms and tried all the solutions but this slightly different as it is only one image(the first) of a series.

Comment: The image in question doesn't happen to have weird characters in its filename? Accented characters, special letters, etc?

Comment: Do you have [GenerateTransformsBeforePageLoad](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#generateTransformsBeforePageLoad) set in your config/general.php?

Comment: Hmm.. @aelvan is probably right and there's something special to that image file in question. You said you actually solved the issue by replacing it with a new "dummy" image, right?

Comment: @aelvan unless you call a dash weird, no.

Comment: Can you check your craft/storage/runtime/logs files for any [error] or [warning] logs that might be related?

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself... The db now has all the files updated to "1". I had before tried changing the config before like @MarionNewlevant suggested without success... tried again and maybe it just needed a couple of tries.

Comment: Hi @AbbeyDesign, welcome to Craft SE! Since this appears to have been an isolated incident which mysteriously resolved itself, we're going to close it as a bug report.